# When two Gramians of square matrices are equal to each other

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider two matrices $A,B\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ such that $A^tA = B^tB$. I want to show that $A$ is a multiple of $B$ in the following sense: there is a matrix $X\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ such that $X^tX= I$ and $A=XB$.

Any hints or suggestions would be fine.

Comment: There is a complete answer in: R.A. Horn, I. Olkin, "When does $A^{*}A=B^{*}B$ and why does one want to know?" Amer. Math. Monthly 103 (1996) 470–482.

Answer (score 4):

Key phrase to look up: polar decomposition.